# Scheduling "pages" for deletion

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

How do I get FB to automatically delete pages after a certain period? Possibly I am doing something terribly wrong but each of my web sites "events" corresponds to a unique url with event specific FB meta data and open graph data. The web app side auto deletes events after the actual event has passed if it has a date and period. The problem is that these pages which have been "shared" to FB continue to exist in FB. e.g consider this long term in the future "event" :-

http://shamrockirishbar.com/event?id=1997

Now when that date has passed then the event is purged from the DB *but* if it has been "shared" to FB then the it appears as one of my FB pages still. How do I set it up to automatically purge from FB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can do this programatically. The Facebook docs for the [Page object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) include a 'create' method but not a 'delete' one.

Comment: Which suggests my approach is wrong in the first place as clearly I don't want thousands of pages lying around months after their events expired. As an aside, I don't want to do it programmatically per se, I would expect fb to do it. I need to review the meta data I think.

Comment: Are you creating pages, or events? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/ It's entirely possible events don't expire because there might be pictures, posts, etc. attached to them that people might find valuable years later.

Comment: I explained in the opening Post how i represent the  unique Events and gave a link to an example. I daresay I need to review this approach. Thanks for your input regardless.